# Delete using superagent in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, superagent

I'm just curious on how should I use delete in superagent, its hard to search for any delete superagent documentation I am currently using asp.net as my API and reactjs as front end I have this button:

```
<td><center><button className ="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.deleteEmployee.bind(this,  d.Employee_ID)}>Delete</button></center></td>
```

How will I connect it on superagent using fetch?
I'm using a localhost:

```
http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/DeleteEmployeeDetail/
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `del()` see the [documentation](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/)

> DELETE can be also called as .del() for compatibility with old IE
>   where delete is a reserved word.

`npm install superagent`

```
var request = require('superagent');

deleteEmployee(id) {
    request
       .del('/api/employeedetails/DeleteEmployeeDetail')
       .send({ id: id })
       .set('Accept', 'application/json')
       .end(function(err, res){});
}
```

Comment: but how will i connect it to the button's id?

Comment: In you function `deleteEmployee` use superagent like the code above.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined

Answer (score 0):

*You may get a 405 error if you directly use a delete request*.

For instance, you may have an endpoint like this one

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->delete('/orders/{id}', 'ApiController@destroyOrder');
```

and you make a delete request using superagent like below

```
superagent
  .del(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/orders/${params.id}`)
  .send(body)
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${process.env.API_TOKEN_SECRET}`)
  .then(response => {})
  .catch(error => {})
```

and got a response like this: "GET method is not supported for this route"

---

**To overcome this issue, here's an alternative:**

```
superagent
  .post(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/api/orders/${params.id}`)
  .send({ _method: "DELETE" })
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${process.env.API_TOKEN_SECRET}`)
  .then(response => {})
  .catch(error => {})
```